# Why can't I see the icon that is compiled inside my Windows program as a binary Resource?

Tags: windows, icons

I had a problem with 256x256 icons in .ico files not saving/showing correctly, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1018500/icon-saved-in-iconworkshop-shows-as-black).

I seem to have solved the problem with the .ico file, but it still shows as a black square when I compile it in my Windows program (compiled with Delphi). The small icon shown in Windows Explorer details is fine, but the large icon shown with thumbnail view remains black. Any suggestions?

**clarification** re Martin's comment
I'm talking about the application icon, for Windows (in particular Explorer), not for use by the program itself. Windows shows the small icon (16x16 I guess) in the details, list, and small icons view, as well as in the taskbar. The 256x256 icon is shown in the extra large icon view.

BTW, I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Verify what sizes and color resolutions are present in your icon file. Then show the code you expect to display the icon. If you are talking about your application icon, tell us where you expect it to be displayed and in what Windows version.

Comment: @downvoter How do you expect me to improve my question if you don't tell me what's wrong with it in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps it's the icon cache. Restart your machine.

Comment: @David That's it! If you post it as an answer (maybe [expanding](https://letsplaymath.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/funny-math-homework.jpg) it a bit), I'll accept it.

Comment: This issue really has nothing to do with Delphi at all (it could help someone using C++ with an icon resource linked as well). I wonder if this should be edited and retagged.

Comment: @Warren I removed the Delphi tags.

Comment: I changed your title too so others who google will find this one. We don't need 80 questions, one for each tool that can embed an .ico in binary resource format, inside an EXE.  On Windows 10, usually you can get around this with killing Explorer.exe from task manager, but sometimes even on Windows 10, I just end up rebooting, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the system has cached the defective icon and is not taking account of your updated icon. This is a common problem. There are various solutions, but far and away the simplest is to restart the machine.